# What is the precedence of `->`, `=` and ` ` in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, operator-precedence

I'm trying to figure out some default operator precedences in Haskell, but I was unable to find some good documentation on `->`, `=` and  (as in `f x`). So I tried `:i (->)` and `:i (=)` in GHCI to get some info, but it gives me a syntax error.

Apparently these "tokens" are just a built-in part of the syntax, so no wonder, that `:i` doesn't work.

I'm new to Haskell, so I wasn't aware of the fact, that `=` doesn't return any value, I just mistakingly assumed, that it behaves as its equivalents in imperative languages, which is wrong of course.

`->` and ,  on the other hand, behave as operators. They return a type/value and are right/left associative respectively. And they have some sort of perecedence when used along with actual operators.

Comment: those are built-in syntax, not functions, so that's why `:i` doesn't work. As for the relative precedence of these "operators", what actual piece of code gives rise to the question?

Comment: Those are not functions defined in Haskell, but language tokens. The precedence can be derived from the [language grammar](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/syntax-iso.html).

Comment: Why do you think `=` is an operator? It doesn't behave like any operator, since it doesn't return anything. Calling it an operator is misguided.

Comment: `:i (->)` doesn't give me a syntax error. It tells me the precendence is `infixr 0`

Comment: @4castle `(->)` is an operator in some sense, e.g. `(->) a` is a functor. However, it is type-level, and thus isn't like other 'operators'

Comment: I never said, that these are operators. I just want to be sure when to use parentheses when dealing with these tokens (thanks for mentioning this term, I didn't know what to call these) and other actual operators. Like for example in `function (head:tail)` the ` ` has some kind of "precedence" that is lower that that of `:`.

Comment: (Edit: I meant "higher precedence".)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- `->` is a type-level operator (`(->) :: * -> * -> *`), and as mentioned in comments, `:i (->)` reveals that it is `infixr 0`*.
- Function application could be seen as having 'infinitely high' left precedence, that is to say if `%` is any operator, then `f x % y` will always be read as `(f x) % y` no matter what precedence `%` has, and `f x y z` is always read as `((f x) y) z`.** This isn't documented as having a precedence, because it isn't an operator, and 'infinite' precedence can't be declared in Haskell.
- `=` cannot be seen as having precendence, as it is always *declaration* rather than an *expression*, so putting parentheses around it is absurd. It is not an operator, hence cannot have precedence.

---

** As pointed out in a below comment, this actually behaves as if it has precedence `infixr -1`, but this is not permitted in ordinary operators — this is syntactic rather than semantic.*

*** Note that this is the 'opposite' of `->`, which could be seen as having 'infinitely low', right precedence. Can you see why this is natural?*

Comment: The question about `=` was based on my mistaken understanding of it, but for the other two this explanation is exactly what I needed.

Comment: A footnote on `(->)`: in spite of what GHCi says, its precedence is `-1` rather than `0`, as discussed in [GHC issue #15235](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/15235) (that is set to be fixed in GHC 8.8.1).

Comment: @duplode That's very helpful, and in fact justifies my characterisation of `->` as having 'infinitely low' precedence. Thank you!

Comment: Also worth noting that record update `x { y = z }` & construction `X { y = z }` have higher precedence than function application, so you can do e.g. `pure SomeRecord { srValue = 42 }` rather than `pure $ SomeRecord …`

Comment: @JonPurdy I believe that's _lower_ precedence, not higher.

Comment: @AJFarmar: No—`pure X { y = z }` is parsed as `pure (X { y = z })`, not `(pure X) { y = z }`

Comment: @JonPurdy Sorry, my mistake—you're right, it's higher.